# Creating array of custom objects in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 100 records of data which is coming to my system from a service. I want to create 100 Class Objects for each record for serializing it to my Custom Class. I was doing this memory creation inside a for loop as follows

```
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
SomeClass s1 = new SomeClass();
//here i assign data to s1 that i received from service
}
```

Is there any way to create all the 100 objects outside the array and just assign data inside the for loop.

```
I already tried Array.newInstance and SomeClass[] s1 = new SomeClass[100]
```

Both result in array of null pointers. Is there any way i can allocate all the memory outside the for loop.

Comment: Don't think of it as "memory creation" (in fact, the memory was already created in some asian factory, and now resides in your computer, in the form of a chip). Think of it as class instance creation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Object[] myArray = new Object[100]
```

Java allocates 100 places to put your objects in. It does NOT instantiate your objects for you.

You can do this:

```
SomeClass[] array = new SomeClass[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
    // set properties
    array[i] = someObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found below really helpful when creating array of custom objects in single line:

```
public class Hotel {
    private int frequency;
    private String name;
    public Hotel(int frequency,String name){
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
public class PriorityQueueTester {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Queue<Hotel> hotelPQ = new PriorityQueue<Hotel>();
        Hotel h[] = new Hotel[]{new Hotel(4,"Harshil"),new Hotel(5,"Devarshi"),new Hotel(6,"Mansi")};
        System.out.println(h[0].getName() + " "+h[1].getName()+" "+h[2].getName());
    } 
}
```