# Does java have the same thing like pascal(type record...end) to sort data?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, pascal

Like this title said, I want to make the same array like pascal in java. But is this possible to make in java?

```
type
  personal = record
              name : string;
              year : smallint;
              sex : string;
              age : integer;
              phone : string;
             end;
var
  PersonalArray : array [1..10] of personal;

  ...
  
  PeterPhone := PersonalArray[1].phone;
```

As i wish to make a program so that i can sort the Users' order by their ages. In pascal, it is possible to swap the **WHOLE** Users' data at once by using these codes.

```
temp := PersonalArray[0];
PersonalArray[0] = PersonalArray[1];
PersonalArray[1] = temp;
```

As i am just a java beginner, i just can't find any similar coding in java can do this for me (i have been finding those codes for a week, but still can't find it...). I just want to have a much faster way to sort them without using a stupid method (Using so many separated arrays to store those data, and simply swap ALL the arrays to sort the Users).

That stupid method i made:

```
//Declaring those array varibles
String[] Narr = new String[100], Parr = new String[100];
int[] Yarr = new int[100], 
byte[] Aarr = new byte[100];
char[] Sex = new int[100];

  ...
//Swaping the Users' Data
NameTemp = Narr[0]; Narr[0] = Narr[1]; Narr[1] = NameTemp; //swap the name array
YearTemp = Yarr[0]; Yarr[0] = Yarr[1]; Yarr[1] = YearTemp; //swap the year array
SexTemp = Sarr[0]; Sarr[0] = Sarr[1]; Sarr[1] = SexTemp; //swap the sex array
AgeTemp = Aarr[0]; Aarr[0] = Aarr[1]; Aarr[1] = AgeTemp; //swap the age array
PhoneTemp = Parr[0]; Parr[0] = Parr[1]; Parr[1] = PhoneTemp; //swap the phone array
```

Do anyone have a better way to code this? Or i can only using those stupid method to solve this problem?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes. You can make arrays of any type in Java. In your case, you'd make a class Personal with name, year, sex, age and phone fields, and the corresponding constructor, getters and setters, and create an array of Personal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating array of custom objects in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402764/creating-array-of-custom-objects-in-java)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable. Stack snippets are only meant for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that can be run on a browser. Please format your code using a [code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.